# How to get current duration of video in exo player?

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I'm using the ExoPlayer library for playing some videos from the online data sources. Everything is working fine.

Now I want to get current video duration/position on every second. I can't get any option in the default event listener. Anyone have any reference, I've searched about it but can't get anything. Please help me to get this.

Here's the event listener functions I'm getting,

```
 @Override
    public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

    }

    
    @Override
    public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekProcessed() {

    }


    @Override
    public void onPlaybackSuppressionReasonChanged(int playbackSuppressionReason) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onIsPlayingChanged(boolean isPlaying) {

    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to get current video position at every second , then run handler for every second and get the current position in seconds as shown below.

**KOTLIN**

```
 var videoWatchedTime = 0L

Handler().postDelayed({
    // Do your work
    videoWatchedTime = player.currentPosition / 1000
}, 1000)
```

**JAVA**

```
long videoWatchedTime =0;
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Do your work
   videoWatchedTime= player.getCurrentPosition()/1000;
        }
    },1000);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will it return the duration time in seconds?

Comment: @kish0n yes it will give duration time in seconds , currentposition gives in milliseconds and divide by 1000 will give it in seconds.

Comment: Yes, I converted it into minutes now. And your solution works fine. Thanks.